# Owl Carousel is not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, owl-carousel

I tried to make a responsive owl carousel but it is not working for some reason. It works with images but it does not work with Youtube videos. Can someone help me?

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WZwr2a_lFWY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dLymsYC7Kmo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M46FRJsB0Qw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6eEZ7DJMzuk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nRYCLOTRAK4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eDEFolvLn0A" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nnVjsos40qk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QqsvrV1_XEA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G8GaQdW2wHc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0nPlIi685DU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                    
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         
          $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            navigation : true,
            autoWidth: true,
            loop: true,
            responsiveClass: true,
            center: true,
            merge: true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items: 1
                    },
                    
                600:{
                    items: 2
                    },
                
                900:{
                    items: 3
                    }
                }
            
          });
         
        });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
#owl-demo .item{
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;

}
```

This is how I want it to be

[image]

But mine is like this, not resizing properly with the change of the browser width

[image]

Comment: project owl carousel was closed about 2 years ago, they did't create any updates/bugfixes  [you can check it](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2) Better do't use it. You can find many good sliders (swiperjs - on native js, slick - jQuery, check [npm trends](https://www.npmtrends.com/lory.js-vs-slick-vs-slick-carousel-vs-swiper-vs-tiny-slider))

Comment: You specify media quires (600px, 900px) and change number items to display, but in your gif it should be always 1. You got the expected result (which you yourself indicated in the code)

Comment: @Greg-- But shouldn't the number of items be 1 when the screen is below 600px?

Comment: Whithout snippet its hard to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you put iframes in the corousel. You don't like read the documentation? ))) Look here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/video.html
To add video into carousel just put `<a class="owl-video" href="_straight URL from YouTube, Vimeo, or vzaar"></a>`.

---

Ok try this:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/WZwr2a_lFWY"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/dLymsYC7Kmo"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/M46FRJsB0Qw"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/nRYCLOTRAK4"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/eDEFolvLn0A"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/nnVjsos40qk"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/QqsvrV1_XEA"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/G8GaQdW2wHc"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video"><a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/0nPlIi685DU"></a></div>   
</div>
```

This:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    loop: true,
    center: true,
    merge: true,
    video:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items: 1
            },            
        600:{
            items: 2
            },        
        900:{
            items: 3
            }
        }    
    }); 
});
</script>
```

And this:

```
<style>
.item-video {height: 300px;}
</style>
```

Result here: https://view.abramovaleksandr.com/

Comment: I've followed this exact same thing before, but the videos did not appear for some reason so I had to resort to using iframes :/

Comment: Answer Updated. I add some code. There your video urls.
Videos did not appear not for some reason))) Reason is - you dont read all documentation))

Comment: I tried this again just like how you did but it shows a black screen with a play button instead of the video thumbnail. The video also doesn't play.

Comment: All code added by me is implemented here: https://view.abramovaleksandr.com/
it's work how you can see. May be you have console errors? Can you show url where is your carousel?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem! I think there's just something wrong when I execute my file, but when I hosted the website, the videos showed up just fine. Thank you for the help!